# Lattice in complex plane

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a homework problem:

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be complex numbers. Under what circumstances is the set of integer combinations $\{\ell\alpha+m\beta+n\gamma:\ell,m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a lattice on the complex plane?

As an attempt, I decided that a lattice on the complex plane must be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then I tried to construct an isomorphism between free modules to determine more about $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. However, I couldn't think of any useful map. Could anyone please give me some ideas/hints?